# Valor inesperado ao calcular a média entre dois números

Tags: javascript

```
var alunos = document.querySelectorAll(".aluno");

for (var registro = 0; registro<alunos.length; registro++) {

  var aluno= alunos[registro];

  var nota1 = aluno.querySelector(".info-nota1").textContent;

  var nota2 = aluno.querySelector(".info-nota2").textContent;

  var tdMedia = aluno.querySelector(".info-media");
  var media = (nota1+nota2)/2;

  aluno.querySelector(".info-media").textContent=media;

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Quando você faz nota1 + nota2, você está concatenando essas variáveis, ao invés de somá-las.
Para resolver, basta usar o `parseint()`

```
var alunos = document.querySelectorAll(".aluno");
for (var registro = 0; registro<alunos.length; registro++) {
  var aluno= alunos[registro];    
  var nota1 = aluno.querySelector(".info-nota1").textContent;    
  var nota2 = aluno.querySelector(".info-nota2").textContent;    
  var tdMedia = aluno.querySelector(".info-media");
  nota1 = parseInt(nota1);
  nota2 = parseInt(nota2);
  var media = (nota1+nota2)/2;    
  aluno.querySelector(".info-media").textContent=media;    
}
```

Comment: Para se pensar: utilizando `parseInt` direto na soma, as variáveis `nota1` e `nota2` serão *strings* durante o resto do programa. Faz sentido ter notas como *string* nesse caso?

Comment: caramba, eu nunca pensaria nisso ;-;. tem como fazer a soma direta sem colocar parseint?

Comment: Corrigi o código, tinha feito errado na rapidez. E @AndersonCarlosWoss este é um ótimo ponto a se pensar.